# ¿Como organizo un vector de objetos por sus atributos en java ?(sin arraylist)

Tags: java, lista

Necesito ordenar un vector de clase Person, y ordenarlo segun la edad, pero sin utilizar el Array

```
  public class Person {
        byte[] years = new byte [5];
        private String name;
        Prueba pruebaObj = new Prueba();
        private byte year;
        public static Person[] listPerson;

public Person(String name, byte year){
    this.setName(name);
    this.setYears(year);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setYears(byte year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public byte getYear(){
    return this.year;
}
public Person[] person(){
    listPerson = new Person[5];
    listPerson[0] = new Person("pedro", (byte) 23);
    listPerson[1] = new Person("juan", (byte)34);
    listPerson[2] = new Person("pepe", (byte)45);
    listPerson[3] = new Person("pablo", (byte)12);
    listPerson[4] = new Person("nada", (byte)78);
    return listPerson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizá el método [Burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja), sería una opción válida, lo único que tendríamos que tener en cuenta es la forma de comparar en el `if` los atributos de la clase.

```
for(int i=0;i<(listPerson.length-1);i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<listPerson.length;j++){
      if(listPerson[i].getEdad()>listPerson[j].getEdad()){
         int aux=listPerson[i].getEdad();
         listPerson[i].setEdad(listPerson[j].getEdad());
         listPerson[j].setEdad((byte) aux);
        }
     }
  }
```

Para comparar los String Usar el método [CompareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) donde el valor devuelto puede ser

- Número positivo: la cadena 1 es mayor que la cadena 2.
- 0: las cadenas son iguales.
- Número negativo: la cadena 1 es menor que la cadena 2.

  ```
     /* Dentro de los dos for sería así. Forma Ascendente por atributo Nombre*/
     if(listPerson[i].getNombre().compareTo(listPerson[j].getNombre())>0){
        String aux=listPerson[i].getNombre();
        listPerson[i].setNombre(listPerson[j].getNombre());
        listPerson[j].setNombre(aux);
     }
  ```